# Project Euler Solution #3 (Java): Debugging

Tags: java, debugging

I've recently started working on Project Euler a while ago, and I've completed the code for problem #3. The task is to find the largest prime factor of a large number(600851475143). I've completed the code in Java, but I have a debugging problem.

[Here's](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) the link.

When I try to run it, it returns this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
>   at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
>   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
>   at main.main(main.java:24)

This is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long n = 600851475143L;
        int factor = 1;
        List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> pfactors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int position = 0;
        int testn = 1;

        while (factor <= n) {
            if (n % factor == 0) {
                factors.add(factor);
                factor++;
            }
            else {
                factor++;
            }

            while (position <= factors.size()) {
                while (factors.get(position) >= testn) {
                    if (factors.get(position) % testn == 0 && testn != 1 && testn != factors.get(position)) {
                        position++;
                    }
                    else {
                        pfactors.add(factors.get(position));
                        position++;
                    }
                }
            }
            int length = pfactors.size();
            System.out.println(pfactors.get(length));
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want a solution to the problem, just a way to fix the bug.

Comment: Start by reading the message. Browse the javadoc of the exception to understand what it means, and when it's thrown. Find the line 24 in your code. Ask yourself why this exception is thrown at that line. Use your debugger if you can't find why.

Comment: Please respect the wish of Project Euler to not share solutions. (`[...] you are requested to be thoughtful in not posting anything that might explicitly give away how to solve a particular problem.` https://projecteuler.net/about.

Answer (score 4):

List indizes are in the range [0, size - 1]. So your `while` condition should be `position < factors.size()` instead of `position <= factors.size()`. Otherwise `factors.get(position)` throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` as soon as `position` is equals `factors.size()`.

Comment: I tried it, but it returned the same error later on.  Is there another problem with the list that I could be missing?

Comment: @hydromend You have the same problem in the line `System.out.println(pfactors.get(length));` (should be `length - 1` instead of `length`).

Comment: I figured that that would be a solution, but when I did try it, it said that it was out of bounds because subtracting 1 from the length would make it negative.  I guess my list has no elements, which doesn't make any sense.  What do you suggest I do?

Comment: You have to check whether the list is empty (`pfactors.isEmpty()`). If so, don’t access the list. If your *algorithm* as such does not work, you should open a new question about the specific problem.